# How to configure Yii2 basic template to multiple projects

Tags: php, apache, yii2

I am new using PHP and Yii2.

I had installed **Yii2 basic template framework** using *Composer* in *Apache* directory **'var/www/html'** and it is working correctly in localhost.

In order to avoid downloading Yii2 framework for every new project I start, I want to load and reuse Yii2 for all projects, instead to modify it all the time.

So, I need to figure out how to load Yii2 in a folder outside basic, like this:

```
var/www/html
|-- basic
    |--assets
    |--commands
    |--config
    |--controllers
    ...
    ...
|--myNewApplication
...
... LOAD OR POINT to **basic** here!
```

And it is the **index.php** file inside **basic/web**:

```
<?php

// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

If someone could help me with it, please!

Thanks!!!

Comment: You should't do such things, think what happens when you upload this to production or try to initiate application on other environment. Every app should have their own `vendor` with all necessary libraries, including `yiisoft`, so pulling app and running `composer install` will prepare application to work

Comment: Did you take a look at yii2 advanced app structure? It has 3 apps frontend, backend and console. You can add as many apps as you want if you follow the folder structure!